# Is it possible to save data natively from a string which is destructed afterwards without moving it elsewhere?

Tags: c++, memory

```
const char* s = std::string("text").c_str();
std::cout << s << std::endl; //This will print nothing because the data
                             //isn't available any longer
```

`std::string::c_str()` returns a pointer to its stored data.
Considering the fact that `std::string("text")` is just available for the time I use it (e.g. when I use it to initialize another instance) so in the end the destructor is called which deletes the data which, in turn, makes `s` pointing to nothing.

Now my question is if there is a native (library-independent) way to keep the raw data alive. Or is it just possible if they would use something like a shared-smart-pointer which knows if something else is pointing to the `std::string`'s data so it is not deleted yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string cannot be made to use reference counted pointers internally.  If you wish to use a pointer to its data, you must make sure the string survives.  The only alternative is copying / moving the data out into another string object.